# What happened to Continental drift in Fringe Prime?

Tags: fringe

In episode 6 of season three, Fringe "6955 kHz". A secret code from a civilization millions of years old (before dinosaurs means more then 230 million years ago), is decoded and leads to the coordinates of items hidden million of years ago.   Continental drift should have moved these all over the world, This would have been during or before Pangaea. (not to mention geological changes like the rise and fall of mountain ranges)

So how is that the latitude and longitude are so accurate the it only takes a couple hours to dig up the first piece they look for?

**I just watched this, and am watching in order so please hide any future spoilers in answers. **

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is a huge spoiler for the end of the season, but

> The "ancient civilization" is actual Peter Bishop, using the Central Park wormhole to hide the Machine, scattering it across the Earth during the time of the dinosaurs, and thus, he would know the correct coordinates in the present time.
>  
>  The wormhole itself is a massive vortex, similar to what Over There had been experiencing for years.

Comment: Myeerp, about 90% correct.  The method used isn't that.  I mean what they used was caused by something that happened because of that, but...  ~is trying not to void the use of spoiler markup~

Comment: Thank you, I will not look until I have watched the full season.

Comment: @Izkata I was working from memory so I may have some of the details wrong. feel free to fix it :)

Comment: Glad I didn't peak, did not see that coming.  I missed the clue(s) that was/where a clue in the final episode and it did not come together for me until the revial, then it all made sense.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Re: "correct coordinates", I still don't get how the "ancient civilization" (maintaining spoiler block) could possibly have known, or been able to predict with much certainty, that placing the machine's parts in XYZ locations millions of years ago would assure they would be found using ABC coordinates in the early 21st century? I assume what you're saying is they would have been able to work out where all those locations would have ended up, but as intelligent as they seem to be, I doubt they had the advanced geological and geophysical knowledge that would have been required.

Comment: The only other options I can think of are (a) they time traveled in order to check that the coordinates/burial locations were suitably matched up, but as we have seen at numerous points in the show prior to this point, time travel is problematic to say the least and somehow I don't think this is how things played out; or (b) the civilization somehow conducted tests with "dummy" objects to verify their predictions of geological displacement.